# Correct term for computer language that's close to human in syntax

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, programming

I've always used the term *canonical syntax* to refer to a computer language, the syntax of which is verbose and resembles the patter in conventional human speech. Recently, I learned that *canonical* actually means *accepted by vast consensus*, so I'm lacking a word in my vocabulary now. Actually I lack two, because the opposite of that I referred to as *uncanonical syntax*.

Example for the different syntaxes' look.

```
 if condition is true  
    then begin call donkey end  
    else begin exit end  
 end if  

 if(condition)  
    donkey();  
 else  
    exit();
```

To make it easier to come up with a great answer, I'm quoting from one of the comments.

> "*Cobol and SQL have **XXX** syntax, while C# and Java have **YYY** syntax, whereas LINQ has both **XXX** and **YYY** syntaxes.*"

What would appropriate values for *XXX* and *YYY* be?

Comment: Grammatical ? ..

Comment: The term from way back when folks actually thought this possible is "natural language syntax".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_programming

Comment: This [article](http://www.byte-notes.com/generation-programming-languages) may help.  I think "fifth-generation" language is what you are looking for.

Comment: You may have to reorganize your thinking. 'Declarative' and 'procedural' are often used to describe different approaches to computer languages that are more ('declarative') or less ('procedural') similar to natural language. See pp. 6-7 at [SQL the natural language for analysis](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/wp-sqlnaturallanguageanalysis-2431343.pdf) for some discussion.

Comment: Actually, if you want a single word use "COBOL".

Comment: @JEL I'm afraid that's not it. Both examples are taken from procedural languages (VB and C#). The same distinction in syntaxes can be made for functional languages (declarative etc.) using SQL and LINQ. In fact, LINQ has both syntaxes available!

Comment: @Josh61 I'd hardly see any of the above as grammatical...

Comment: @HotLicks I wouldn't mind an adjective for that. It's cumbersome to say *it's a naturally syntaxed  language* and it's even more quirky to say *it's an unnaturally syntaxed language*. Although, I have to admit, the term **does indeed** correspond to what it looks like...

Comment: @cobaltduck I'm not entirely sure that's the thing. I can imagine both naturally syntaxed and unnaturally syntaxed languages on the same generational tier... Also, it's not communicative to someone who doesn't have the definition of which generation corresponds to which feature.

Comment: @cobaltduck - After "3rd generation" that scheme for identifying categories of programming languages pretty much fell apart.  Everyone touted their scheme for language "improvement" as the "next generation" and there was precious little agreement.

Comment: "Canonical" in computing also sometimes refers to a certain preferred form of some object which exists in several equivalent forms.  When those forms are processed, reducing them to the single canonical form in some earlier processing stage simplifies the later one, which only deals with the canonical form, and ignores the other cases.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps *English-like*.

From the 1950's, [Admiral Grace Hopper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper) promoted the idea that computers should be programmed using English words rather than numerical codes. She is often cited as the inventor of the compiler and credited for the development of the [COBOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL) language, one of the first high-level programming languages.

> COBOL (/ˈkoʊbɒl/, an acronym for common business-oriented language) is a compiled *English-like* computer programming language designed for business use.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL)</sub>

Below is a sample of COBOL syntax ([by Michael Coughlan](http://www.csis.ul.ie/cobol/examples/Conditn/IterIf.cbl))

```
PERFORM 3 TIMES
   DISPLAY "Enter First Number      : " WITH NO ADVANCING
   ACCEPT Num1
   DISPLAY "Enter Second Number     : " WITH NO ADVANCING
   ACCEPT Num2
   DISPLAY "Enter operator (+ or *) : " WITH NO ADVANCING
   ACCEPT Operator
   IF Operator = "+" THEN
      ADD Num1, Num2 GIVING Result
   END-IF
   IF Operator = "*" THEN
      MULTIPLY Num1 BY Num2 GIVING Result
   END-IF
   DISPLAY "Result is = ", Result
END-PERFORM.
```

---

As prompted in a [comment by ermanen](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300942/correct-term-for-computer-language-thats-close-to-human-in-syntax/300944#comment678165_300944), if the language syntax is meant to be very close to forming grammatically correct sentences, then the term [*natural-language-like*](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22natural-language-like%20programming%22&tbm=bks&rct=j) could be applied. The whole endeavor could be categorized as [*natural language programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_programming), as [noted by HotLicks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300942/correct-term-for-computer-language-thats-close-to-human-in-syntax/300944#comment678129_300942).

Comment: Well, Cobol would be an example of such a language. What would you say here? "*Cobol and SQL have **XXX** syntax, while C# and Java have **YYY** syntax, whereas LINQ has both **XXX** and **YYY** syntaxes.*"

Comment: Yeah, COBOL was going to allow managers to program (and SQL would allow them to run database queries).  That lasted about 5 minutes.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I got side-tracked by on of the comments and though that *Cobol* was your answer. My bad. Well, it's at least a good attempt, although I hoped for a "real" adjective. What would you say the opposite of that be? I know that both Russians and French constructed languages that were Cobol-like but definitely not English-like...

Comment: I often hear programming language syntax described in terms of the languages they resemble. So *C-like* or *Pascal-like* or *LISP-like* are things I would understand when presented to me. So *COBOL-like* should be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Well, it is going to be a bit clumsy but you can use the adjective "natural-language-like" to cover all natural languages. You can find some examples in Google Books also: https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22natural-language-like+programming%22&tbm=bks

Comment: [Example of someone wanting to make C++ more English-like.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34877961/315052)